# How to solve issue with groupby on a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I wish to have a final dataframe with a index of projects, a list of exchanges and a last column for price.

Here is an example:

```
data = {'Exchange': ['coinbase', 'binance', 'coinbase', 'ftx','coinbase'], 'Projects': ['Bitcoin', 'Bitcoin', 'Ethereum', 'Ethereum','Doge'],'Price': [10,5,10,2,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Output : 
   Exchange  Projects  Price
0  coinbase   Bitcoin     10
1   binance   Bitcoin      5
2  coinbase  Ethereum     10
3       ftx  Ethereum      2
4  coinbase      Doge     10
```

Here is what I tried

```
df2 = df.groupby(by=["Projects"]).count()


df2['Price'] = df['Price']

df2['Exchange'] = df['Exchange']

df2

Output:

          Exchange  Price
Projects        
Bitcoin     NaN      NaN
Doge        NaN      NaN
Ethereum    NaN      NaN
```

What I wish to have:

```
            Exchange          Price
Projects        
Bitcoin     coinbase,binance  10
Doge        coinbase,ftx      2
Ethereum    ftx               5
```

Comment: How do you get 10, 2, 5 for Price? Please check your input and your output. Why 'Doge' has 'coinbase,ftx' in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
out = df.groupby('Projects').agg({'Exchange': ','.join,'Price':'last'})
Out[35]: 
                  Exchange  Price
Projects                         
Bitcoin   coinbase,binance      5
Doge              coinbase     10
Ethereum      coinbase,ftx      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby_agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Projects').agg({'Exchange': ','.join, 'Price': 'last'})

                  Exchange  Price
Projects                         
Bitcoin   coinbase,binance      5
Doge              coinbase     10
Ethereum      coinbase,ftx      2
```

You can replace `'last'` by another function like `'max'`, `'mean'`, `'min'` or a custom function.

Comment: thank you for the help! but here we are not getting the different prices... but still great help. I will find a way